# How to combine 2 conditions and more in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I want to create a regex that match '.', '#' and ':' **and also match everything inside these brackets '[' & ']'** such as [foo] & [bar]

I already have this match `string.match(/[.#:]/g)` for '.','#' and ':'.

I know that the brackets regex should look like this `\[.\]`

but how do I combine them both to one condition?

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to combine them use

```
/[.#:]|(?:\[.+?\])/g
```

?: is optional and is used to not capture the group (anything in parenthesis)

UPDATE:

`.+?` (one or more) or `.*?`(for zero or more)- use this for lazy matching, otherwise **[** sdfsdf][sdfsddf **]** will be matched

Comment: dot isn't a metacharacter inside the character class brackets.

Comment: sure. feels good to take those backslashes out kinda doesn't it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "a . b # c : d [foo]";
var m = /[.:#]|\[.*?\]/g;
s.match(m);
// returns [".", "#", ":", "[foo]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '[content]kjalksdjfa.sdf[sc.tt].#:';
var myregexp = /(\[.+?\])|[.#:]/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(data);
var result = "Matches:\n";
while (match != null) {
    result +=  "match:"+match[0] + ',\n';
    match = myregexp.exec(data);
}
alert(result);
```