# Using Regex OR operator to solve 2 conditions

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to combine 2 regular expressions into 1 with the OR operator: `|`

I have one that checks for match of a letter followed by 8 digits:

```vb
Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[A-Z]\d{8}$")
```

I have another that checks for simply 9 digits:

```vb
Regex.IsMatch(s, "^\d{9}$")
```

Now, Instead of doing:

```vb
If Not Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[A-Z]\d{8}$") AndAlso
   Not Regex.IsMatch(s, "^\d{9}$") Then 
    ...
End If
```

I thought I could simply do:

```vb
If Not Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[A-Z]\d{8}|\d{9}$") Then
    ...
End If
```

Apparently I am not combining the two correctly and apparently I am horrible at regular expressions.  Any help would be much appreciated.

And for those wondering, I did take a glance at [How to combine 2 conditions and more in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409171/how-to-combine-2-conditions-and-more-in-regex) and I am still scratching my head.

Comment: Another way to write it would be `"^[A-Z0-9]\d{8}$"` (an uppercase letter or number followed by 8 numbers). I don't see a problem with your regex, though. Can you provide some examples of strings that should / should not match?

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Valid entries would be: A1234578 OR 123456789

Comment: @Scott Patrick's suggestion supports both, as does Mike C's answer below with the same regex.

Comment: Scott - normally, if i see that someone beat me out with the same answer, I will delete my post - however, the times I am seeing are showing that I was first by a minute. The choice is yours, tho :-)

Comment: If you'd find it useful at all, I provided a possible explanation as to why your expression might not be working like you expect, though I can't be sure as there are no details as to _how_ your expression was failing :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about using `^[A-Z0-9]\d{8}$` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't try that during my tinkering. Regex gives me tired head when I start thinking about it, lol.

Answer (score 56):

The `|` operator has a high precedence and in your original regex will get applied first.  You should be combining the two regex's w/ grouping parentheses to make the precedence clear.  As in:

```
"^(([A-Z]\d{8})|(\d{9}))$"
```

Comment: Just curious about the semantics of your statement: are you not counting the grouping parentheses as "operator"s? If not, what are they? "construct"s?

Comment: Well, yes, you're correct -- I'm being imprecise w/ my language.  It's a habit from explaining it to people -- they naturally accept that grouping parentheses override the order of precedence and then think about all the other operators after that.  But it's good to be exact, so I'll clarify.

Comment: @CodeJockey I've considered writing more, but your answer provides an excellent summary of this case, and there's no need to repeat it.

Comment: 'operator has a high precedence and in your original regex will get applied first' Thank you so much for pointing out this!

Answer (score 12):

I think you want to group the conditions:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, "^(([A-Z]\d{8})|(\d{9}))$")
```

The ^ and $ represent the beginning and end of the line, so you don't want them considered in the or condition.  The parens allow you to be explicit about "everything in this paren" or "anything in this other paren"

Answer (score 9):

@MikeC's offering seems the best:

```
^[A-Z0-9]\d{8}$
```

...but as to why your expression is not working the way you might expect, you have to understand that the `|` "or" or "alternation" operator has a very high precedence - the only higher one is the grouping construct, I believe. If you use your example:

```
^[A-Z]\d{8}|\d{9}$
```

...you're basically saying "match beginning of string, capital letter, then 8 digits OR match 9 digits then end of string" -- if, instead you mean "match beginning of string, then a capital letter followed by 8 digits then the end of string OR the beginning of the string followed by 9 digits, then the end of string", then you want one of these:

```
^([A-Z]\d{8}|\d{9})$
^[A-Z]\d{8}$|^\d{9}$
```

Hope this is helpful for your understanding

Comment: I actually tried `^[A-Z]\d{8}$|^\d{9}$` at http://regexpal.com/ before posting, but it wasn't working for me.  Oddly enough, I went back and tried it again, and now it does.  However, MikeC's answer does the exact same thing without the need for the OR.  So, that to me is the best case scenario. +1 for effort and explanation though.

Answer (score 5):

I find the `OR` operator a bit weird sometimes as well, what I do I use groups to denote which sections I want to match, so your regex would become something like so: `^(([A-Z]\d{8})|(\d{9}))$`

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for the tip. I have updated the answer I gave.