# RegularExpressionValidator that get a regular expression of either Email or numbers or English characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I'm trying to set a regular expression to `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` that gets either an Email , numbers (0-9) , or English characters (a-z A-Z) .

When I try to put them with an OR operation between them :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegFieldUserCodeLoginM" CssClass="" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="LoginGroup"  
Text="Only English characters and numbers are allowed , email addresses included!" 
ValidationExpression="\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z | ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The regular expression doesn't work .

How can I do an OR operation between both of them ?

Thanks

Comment: Make it easy. Just add two validator separatly for your TextBox1

Comment: And also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10094594/3745022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove space at both side the `|` mark between two expression:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegFieldUserCodeLoginM" CssClass="" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="LoginGroup"  
Text="Only English characters and numbers are allowed , email addresses included!" 
ValidationExpression="\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```